# Why useEffect doesn't call callback function if state doesn't change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code(react 16.8.6, react-dom: 16.8.6):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function App(props) {
   const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

   console.log(1)

   useEffect(() => {
    console.log(2)

     setTimeout(() => {
       console.log(3)

       setCounter(1);
     }, 10000)
   });

   return  counter;
 }

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

When `App` component is rendered first time, it prints:

> 1
>   2

After 10 seconds it prints:

> 3, 1, 2

Everything that was before is understandable for me, but now after 10 seconds it prints

> 3, 1

i.e. function that is passed to useEffect isn't called. I assume it's related to state somehow (as it doesn't change, if it changes useEffect works fine). Could you explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [React docs:](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update)

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects. (React uses the Object.is comparison algorithm.)
>
> Note that React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree. If you’re doing expensive calculations while rendering, you can optimize them with useMemo.

Thats exactly what happens here: The component rerenders, but as the current state is 1 and you set it to 1 after the second timeout React "bails out" and thus does not retrigger the effect.

---

Sidenote: The effect should really only depend on `counter`, not on an update in general.

Comment: I figured out that such behaviur shows after 16.8.0-alpha.1

You answer seems pretty reasonable. But it's so not obvious from the docs

Comment: Yeah, I searched quite some time to find that part.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks)

> Does useEffect run after every render? Yes! By default, it runs both after the first render and after every update. (We will later talk about how to customize this.) Instead of thinking in terms of “mounting” and “updating”, you might find it easier to think that effects happen “after render”. React guarantees the DOM has been updated by the time it runs the effects.

An update never occurred after you call `setCounter` a second time, because `1 === 1` is always the same.

If you actually increment your counter by one every time you'll get your desired effect.

```
function App(props) {
   const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

   console.log(1)

   useEffect(() => {
    console.log(2)

     setTimeout(() => {
       console.log(3)

       setCounter(counter + 1);
     }, 10000)
   });

   return counter;
}
```

[Live example](https://b513q.csb.app/)

Comment: Do I understand correctly if DOM doesn't change (i.e. update), useEffect isn't called?
i.e. by update they mean DOM update, not state update through setState?

Comment: ... because then the current state and the state to set equal, thus React doesn't rerender. Good catch :)

Comment: @RomanRoman No! React abstracts away the DOM, you never have to work / react on it directly. This is purely related to the state.

Comment: But according to the OP, 1 is logged again ... Why is that? Shouldn't it not rerender at all?

Comment: @JonasWilms Ok. It seems I don't understand something. Let me explain my position. When setTimeout's callback is executed last time(in my case) it produces to print 1. It confuses me

Comment: Yeah, now it confuses me too :) I'd expect that it doesn't do anything at all, but for some reason it does rerender (logs 1), but doesnt retrigger the effect as stated by this answer. I'd expect it to only log 3. And the effect should really depend on `counter` and not on every rerender.

Answer (score 1):

Every time your component renders, useEffect will be called because you do not provide an array as a second parameter.

If you read the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), you will read, that if you do not provide a second parameter, it will be called every time.

If you provide an empty array, it will only be called on the first render.

If you provide a variable into the array, it will only be executed if that variable changes.

3,1 will be called because after the 2 is called, the timeout is set again and will print 3. After updating the state with `setCounter(1);`, the component rerenders and 1 will be called again.

Hope this helps. Happy coding.

Comment: I don't provide the second parameter to useEffect and it's not called every time

Comment: You just described why the code shown by the OP doesn't work as expected.

Comment: It calls 2 and 3 so the useEffect is called? Or do I misunderstand your question.

Comment: @Domino987 It prints 3, then 1 and then useEffect isn't called and 2 isn't printed

Comment: @RomanRoman If you look at this [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-o8u7l), which is your code it gets triggered again and again. What happens if you set the timeout to 500 ms in your code?

Comment: @Domino987 Try this version https://b513q.csb.app/
It won't work. Probably this behaviour depends on react's version

Comment: What version are you using, It should not depend on the react version. The useEffect hook did not change since it got released. Can you share the code for that link you postet?

Comment: @Domino987 16.8.6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197834/discussion-between-domino987-and-roman-roman).